# How to use Simple Stripe Checkout in salesforce

Tags: httpresponse, post

I am trying to use the Stripe's Simple Checkout Demo with Salesforce to receive a token.  Can someone help me figure out why this simple demo does not work?  I am not receiving any value in the requestBody.  I can see in Stripe that the token is being sent from Stripe.  The problem appears to be in the Controller.

I am using Sites in Salesforce.  The page displays with the blue Pay with Card button, and the test credit card 42...42 appears to process correctly (green checkmark appears).  I get to the assert in my code (see below), but the json variable is blank.

My apex page is:

```
<apex:page controller="TestBillingController" >

     <html >
         <form action="https://partial-citywidebuildingservices.cs17.force.com/Forms/services/apexrest/testbillingcontroller" method="POST">
             <script
                 src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                 data-key="pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh"
                 data-image="/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
                 data-name="Stripe.com"
                 data-description="2 widgets"
                 data-amount="2000"
                 data-locale="auto">
             </script>
         </form>
     </html>

</apex:page>
```

My Controller is:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/testbillingcontroller')
 global class TestBillingController {

     /* Constants */

     public static final String ID_PARAM = 'id';

     /* Constructor */

     public TestBillingController() {

     }

     @HttpPost 
     global static ResponseData createCustomer() { 
         Blob theBlob = RestContext.request.requestBody;
         String json = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString(); 
         system.assert(false, 'json = ' + json);
         RequestPayload payload = (RequestPayload) System.JSON.deserialize(json, RequestPayload.class); 
         }
 }
```

In the console I get an error:

POST https://checkout.stripe.com/api/account/verifications 400 (Bad Request)send @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:5jQuery.extend.ajax @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:5ravenAjaxWrapper @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:7API.request @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:10Account.createAuthorization @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:9AccountLookupStepController.willAppear @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:12(anonymous function) @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:12StepController.setCurrent @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:15NavigationController.setCurrent @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:14(anonymous function) @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:14(anonymous function) @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:15NavigationController.push @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:14(anonymous function) @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:14CheckoutController.onAuthorizingAccountChanged @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:14(anonymous function) @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:13EventDispatcher.trigger @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:10(anonymous function) @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:10Account.setAuthorizingAccount @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:9$.extend.callback @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:9(anonymous function) @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:9fire @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:2self.fireWith @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:2(anonymous function) @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:2fire @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:2self.fireWith @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:2deferred.(anonymous function) @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:2fire @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:2self.fireWith @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:2done @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:5callback @ inner-7tNANE4oRmloWnGX9pPpzQ.js:5
 checkout.js:2

POST https://partial-citywidebuildingservices.cs17.force.com/Forms/services/apexrest/testbillingcontroller 500 (Internal Server Error)Button.onToken @ checkout.js:2(anonymous function) @ checkout.js:2TokenCallback.trigger @ checkout.js:2(anonymous function) @ checkout.js:2(anonymous function) @ checkout.js:2IframeView.closed @ checkout.js:2(anonymous function) @ checkout.js:2RPC.processMessage @ checkout.js:1(anonymous function) @ checkout.js:1RPC.message @ checkout.js:1(anonymous function) @ checkout.js:1

> Navigated to https://partial-citywidebuildingservices.cs17.force.com/Forms/services/apexrest/testbillingcontroller

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Token is being sent from Stripe.  The problem appears to be in the controller.

Comment: Now have the token.  Had to get it from request.params.

Comment: i am getting this error : [ { "errorCode": "APEX_ERROR", "message": "StripeException: Script-thrown exception\n\nClass.StripeCustomer: line 203, column 1\nClass.StripeCustomer: line 110, column 1\nClass.StripeCustomer.create: line 82, column 1\nClass.CustomRestService.createCustomer: line 9, column 1" } ] how can achieve this